# Measurement Protocol events not showing in one property where it does in others

Tags: google-analytics, measurement-protocol

I am firing events via the Measurement Protocol which work from my local environment, set up with it's own property, which are showing in Real Time Data.
A separate property for our staging environment works too, the events are shown in Real Time Data.

However this is not working (no events show in Real Time Data) in our production environment (again, under a separate property).

The property may have been set up long before the others, however the same js and server side code is used across the environments with a dynamic property ID. I cannot see any settings or filters on the property which differs from the others.

The Measurement Protocol response when testing all environments come back with a 200 status and a 1x1 GIF as the response (which I expect).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In [Google analytics](https://analytics.google.com) go to the admin settings.  Find the property in question which is not working.   Go to the settings look for.

[image]

Measurement protocol data looks a lot like a bot inserting data into your account.  If bot filtering is enabled it wont be recoreded.

Comment: Same issue in GA4, but it seems this option has since been removed and rendered "magical" on behalf of the Google Team. Any tips for structuring Measurement Protocol data to not be filtered?

Comment: In GA4 the api_secret must be sent and configured from the account itself.  There should be no need to filter for bots only someone who has access to the account and can create an api_secret would be able to send hits to hit.